# Clear angle quotes on phpMalier from parameter

Tags: php, phpmailer

My message on from parameter comming with angles quotes, like that:

```
MyFromName <New message!>
```

I try `$mail->ClearAllRecipients()`, but not work.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. You can't do this. It's part of [the email specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4), which says a mailbox (which is the thing you're talking about) is made up of:

```
mailbox         =   name-addr / addr-spec

name-addr       =   [display-name] angle-addr

angle-addr      =   [CFWS] "<" addr-spec ">" [CFWS] /
                   obs-angle-addr
```

That means an address can be in one of two forms when it appears in a header; as a name and address:

```
User Name <user@example.com>
```

Or as just an address:

```
user@example.com
```

Nearly everything uses the former, and usually if the name is given, that is displayed in preference to the address part, however, that is *entirely* up to the client application you're using to display the message, over which you have no control at all.

If you remove the angle brackets and keep the name, your message will never arrive because it's an invalid format.

Comment: I suspect that, tks for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a replace function, for example;

```
function removeAngleBrackets($from)
{
    // Create an array of things to replace
    // Use both standard and html encoded to cover basis (you could use the ASCII too)
    $replace = array("<", ">", "&lt;", "&gt;");
    // Create the variable to replave the strings with
    $replace_with = "";
    // Replace this in the string and return the value when done
    return str_replace($replace, $replace_with, $from);
}
```

Calling this on your string will remove the angle braces